# The question about the char code of C/C++ AND Java

Tags: java, c++, c

I try to enter the code for the emoji with Unicode code \U+1F431 like this:

[image: img]

This is done on VS Studio 2019. The file encoding of CPP is UTF8-BOM.
C/C++ language in the char occupies only a byte, need two bytes 2 ^ 16 = 65536 to say Chinese characters. In Java, Unicode is used as the internal code, and char is encoded in UTF-16, one char are two bytes, you need to use two char (4 bytes) to represents a single emoji, why emoji just use two bytes in the C language can be said?

In addition, in this online C++ runtime environment(https://c.runoob.com/compile/12), run the same code, output is 4, the character encoding of the http request from the page is UTF-8, the results I understand should be the number of bytes in this emoji encode by UTF-8, but why is not the same as the result of the execution? Will the results of C++ programs still be affected by file encoding? It is always same whatever file encoding in Java

[image: img]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "";
    printf("%d", strlen(str));
    // output is 2 in VS Studio and 4 in the online C++ runtime environment

    char str1[] = "哈";
    printf("%d", strlen(str1));
    // output is 2 in VS Studio and 3 in the online C++ runtime environment
}
```

Comment: A good starting point: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: As is, this is a very confusing question. Please edit your question and provide some code examples.

Comment: C/C++ doesn't know about unicode.  In Visual Studio you have to select Unicode support in your project settings and use the appropriate (wide character) functions and data types.

Comment: @Gyro Gearless I didn't know how to upload pictures the first time I asked, but it's been added. I hope I can get your help

Comment: No, @user15129239, *do not* upload pictures.  We always want code as text.  Likewise console input and output.  Use images only when text cannot serve.

Comment: I konw this. so your meaning is that char can not express emoji correctly. the output: 2 in img1 or 4 in img2 is error? but what if I set like this: char str[] = “哈”, the output is 2 in vs studio and 3 in the online c++ runtime environment, that is my question

Comment: @John Bollinger OK. I've added the code, it's not long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The file encoding of CPP is UTF8-BOM.

I assume that you are talking about the encoding of your particular source file, as opposed to asserting something about the C++ language.  In fact, however, the encoding of your source file is not relevant as long as you and your compiler agree about it and the compiler supports it.  C and C++ distinguish between the encoding of source files (the source character set) and the encoding of character data in runtime memory (the execution character set).  They do not require these to be the same.  The `strlen()` function, being executed at runtime, will evaluate the number of bytes in the runtime encoding of your C string literal.

> C/C++ language in the char occupies only a byte, need two bytes 2 ^ 16 = 65536 to say Chinese characters.

How many bytes are required to encode Chinese characters depends on the character and the encoding.  For example, with Unicode encoded in UCS-4, *all* characters require four bytes.

With Unicode encoded according to UCS-2, all characters require two bytes, but fewer than 65536 characters can be represented at all -- the Unicode "basic multilingual plane".  All Chinese characters that can be represented at all occupy two bytes in this encoding, just like every other character.

With UTF-16, some characters require two bytes and others require four.  Unicode maps many Chinese characters that it considers less commonly used to code points outside the BMP, and these require four bytes in UTF-16.

With UTF-8, all characters outside the BMP require four bytes.  Most BMP characters require three bytes, but some require fewer.

This is by no means an exhaustive list of alternatives.

> In Java, Unicode is used as the internal code, and char is encoded in UTF-16, one char are two bytes, you need to use two char (4 bytes) to represents a single emoji, why emoji just use two bytes in the C language can be said?

[Unicode encodes all emoji outside the BMP](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html).  Two bytes is not sufficient to convey their Unicode codes, no matter what encoding is chosen.  For example, your particular emoji is U+1F431, "cat face".  Its Unicode code point has 17 significant bits.  It cannot be represented in UCS-2, its representation in UTF-16 has four bytes, and its representation in UTF-8 also has four bytes.

Therefore, the output of your program probably shows that either the source is buggy or that it has not been built correctly by VS.  You can probably view it either way, as the most likely problem is that VS is assuming a different source character set than the one with which your source file is actually encoded.  It might be instructive to print the strings, too, as opposed to just their lengths, or to examine them at runtime with VS's debugger.

Your Chinese character example is Unicode character U+54C8.  Its representation in UCS-2 and UTF-16 has two bytes, and the one in UTF-8 has three bytes.  VS is again doing something strange here (see below), probably again because of a disagreement between you and it about the source character set.

> In addition, in this online C++ runtime environment(https://c.runoob.com/compile/12), run the same code, output is 4, the character encoding of the http request from the page is UTF-8, the results I understand should be the number of bytes in this emoji encode by UTF-8, but why is not the same as the result of the execution?

Yes and no.  It is very unlikely (but not impossible) that the online environment you are using takes the encoding of your HTTP requests into account for determining the C++ implementation's execution character set, which is what matters for `strlen()`.  But if it is any good then it *does* take the request encoding into account with respect to the source character set, either by transcoding to a chosen standard encoding or by telling the compiler which source encoding to use on a case-by-case basis.  Thus, it is reasonable to believe that the online environment does not suffer from any source-encoding disagreement such as I have raised as the likely issue in VS.

UCS4, UCS-2, and UTF-16 are not viable execution character sets for C and C++ because the encodings of many non-null characters contain null bytes.  C and C++ implementations will not use those.  (Wide strings are a different consideration.)  Implementations may have options for a variety of execution character sets, but UTF-8 is a common default.  That's because it's a pretty good choice, not because of the encoding of any particular external data.

The output of your program in the online environment is consistent with UTF-8 being that environment's choice of execution character set.

> Will the results of C++ programs still be affected by file encoding? It is always same whatever file encoding in Java

The results of C++ programs can be affected by the implementation's execution character set.  When I/O is involved, you also have to consider the encoding of the external data. As you observe, Java is different -- the internal representation of character data in terms of its `char` data type and `java.lang.String` class is not permitted to vary across implementations.  However, you may still run into trouble with Java if there is a disagreement over source file encoding, and with Java you still have to take character encoding into account when you perform I/O.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think I have found the reason for the exception of vs output. The default execution character set of vs studio 2019 is encoded as GBK. You need to use the following code to make the output normal.
`code`
char str1[] = u8"哈";
`code`

Comment: But I still have some questions, char can support UTF-8 coding, why C + + will also introduce wide character wchar_t ? Under UTF-8 coding, some people say that the reason for using wide characters is that a character can represent a Chinese character, but for Emoji expressions, a wide character can't represent a single emoji. In addition, there is a conversion between ASCII and Unicode in windows, that is char and wchar_t conversion, maybe not right, what does this code conversion mean?

Comment: @user15129239, wide characters and wide strings were introduced before UTF-8 strings.  `wchar_t` and wide strings support *implementation-specific* character representations with *fixed-size* units.  This is amenable to a whole set of analogues of the original string functions.  At the time these were designed, it was not yet evident that they would prove too limited in practice, and UTF-8 had not yet achieved the ubiquity it now has.

Comment: As for conversions between wide and narrow strings, that would be the subject of a different question.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for your answer. It's very helpful. 

Comment: You are welcome, @user15129239.  If your original question has been answered to your satsifaction, then it is customary to "accept" one of the answers by clicking on the check mark icon next to it.